# Missing modifier and scene selection windows (Sorry, I'm a newbie)

Tags: windows

I'm just starting out with blender and currently doing the "Donut" tutorial. It was recommended since it encompasses many aspects of modeling and is great for beginners. In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=4&ab_channel=BlenderGuru) @5:49, he gets into showing how to split the screen. Well I messed up at some point and had windows everywhere. I fixed it, but in the process accidently pushed out my modifier and scene selection windows. I've tried looking online and saw someone with somewhat of a similar problem where the solution was to press <kbd>F9</kbd> but unfortunately it does nothing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is probably to save your blend file to the desktop or somewhere convenient with the layout as it is. Then close Blender and restart it. That will give you the default layout.
Then go to <kbd>File > Open</kbd> to bring up the file selector window. Press <kbd>N</kbd> or click the gearwheel icon indicated below to show the selector properties panel, uncheck the <kbd>Load</kbd><kbd>UI</kbd> checkbox then select your file and click <kbd>Open</kbd>. That will open your file with the default layout preserved.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That worked! You've made my day kind stranger.

Comment: @Lightfoot Glad to hear it. Please click on the check mark beside my answer to accept it. Thanks.